# Not able to run Unit Test case in xcode 14.3

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

**When I run the test cases test failed and through errors**

- Undefined symbol: _$s10Intoto_iOS15LoginValidationV05emailD00E0AA0D8ResponseVSSSg_tF
- Undefined symbol: _$s10Intoto_iOS15LoginValidationVACycfC
- Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If anyone face this issue please help me to resolve the error

I have written the simple test case like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggsz3.png)

Comment: Did you import the class into the tests target? Is `result` visible (not private)?

Comment: Did you annotate the import statement with @testable?

Answer (score -1):

For my case, recreating test scheme (or test target) resolved the problem.[image]